# Force derived class to implement a private method

Tags: c++, inheritance

Is there a way, I can force a derived class to implement an interface through a private function. What I want is the following.

```
class base{
private:
    virtual void do_something() = 0; // This can be private/public/protected
};
```

The derived class MUST provide the implementation of `do_something()` which is not public. As you can guess, my objective here is to make the user give an implementation of a function but make sure that the base class is the one that will call it and an object of the `class derived : public base{...}` won't ever be able to call `do_something()` on its own?

EDIT: Just wanted to add, the `class derived : base` will be written by the user and not by me. The use case is to make sure that functions of the base class control when do_something() is called.

Comment: What's your actual use case for wishing to do so?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Template method pattern?

Comment: Do you mean you don't want `derived` to be able to call `do_something()` internally?

Comment: I only want the methods in base class to be able to call the methods from derived class. This is to control the order of execution.

Comment: @juanchopanza I usually use `protected` for this pattern.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ NVI idiom suggests to use private virtual methods. See [here](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ But there is no need for protected. It gives too much access anyway. You don't usually want derived types to call the overridden methods directly.

Comment: it is not 100% clear, do you mean "force the subclass to implement it" or "force the subclass to implement it as private" ?

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: **No**.

---

Given

```
class base {
private:
    virtual void do_something() = 0;
};
```

you can't force a derived class to implement `do_something` as private. The following is legal:

```
struct derived : base {
    void do_something() { ... }  // public
};
```

---

Even if you could force it to be private, a class can always call its own private methods. That would run counter to your requirement that "*an object of the `class derived : public base{...}` won't ever be able to call `do_something()` on its own*".

---

And even if you could force derived classes to implement a method without being able to call it, they could still work around it like this:

```
struct derived2 : base {
    void do_something_impl() { .... }
private:
    void do_something() { do_something_impl(); }
};
```

Now they can just call `do_something_impl()` directly.

Comment: Yeah, the first case is what puzzled me. Even if I declare a function as private virtual in the base class, a public function from a derived class can override it. I would have thought that this was not possible, but apparently the code compiles. So it must be legal c++.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that instead of declaring `do_something` as a class member you may require derived class to pass function object in a constructor call. But this is ugly -- I'd rather drop requirement for "not able to call from derived" and use `protected`.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class base {
public:
  base(std::function<void()> do_something) : _do_something(do_something) {}
  void act() {
    _do_something();
  }

private:
  std::function<void()> _do_something;
};

class derived : public base {
public:
  derived() : base([&]{std::cout << "impl: " << prop1 << ", " << prop2 << std::endl;}) {}

private:
  int prop1;
  int prop2;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  derived d;
  d.act();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.
See the nice answer by @melpomene.

---

If the problem is that it would be publicly accessible to the one that has a reference to the derived class, you can do this:

```
class base {
private:
    virtual void do_something() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class intermediate: public base, private T {
    void do_something() override {
        T::do_something();
    }
};

class derived {
public:
    void do_something() { }
};

int main() {
    auto *d = new intermediate<derived>{};
    base *b = d;
    // not allowed, it's private
    // d->do_somerhing();
    // b->do_something();
}
```

Within certain limits you can even simulate *inherited data members* (well, I know, they are not inherited at all, but the *friend* can help here):

```
template<typename T>
class intermediate: public base, private T {
    friend T;

    void do_something() override {
        T::do_something(*this);
    }

private:
    int foo;
};

class derived {
public:
    void do_something(intermediate<derived> &ref) {
    ref.foo = 42;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A derived class does not have access to `private` members of a base class.  If a derived class must override `do_something()` then it should be `protected instead:

```
class base
{
protected:
    virtual void do_something() = 0;
};
```

If `do_something()` must be `private` then you should declare a `protected` method that `do_something()` calls and derived classes override. Especially if `do_something()` needs to do other things that derived classes should not override.

```
class base
{
private:
    void do_something()
    {
        //...
        actually_do_something();
        //...
    }

protected:
    virtual void actually_do_something() = 0;
};
```